# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an issue with a jQuery ajax call. If I comment out the ajax call, it is works. It is passing all the validations and going to else which have ajax call. if i put some alert by commenting ajax call, it is working fine and showing the alert.

error in console : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

```
function submit() {
  var companyname = $('#companyname').val();
  var fname = $('#fname').val();
  var username = $('#email').val();
  var countrycode = $('#country-code').val();
  var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
  var captcha = $('#captcha').val();
  var countryid = $('#country-list').val();
  var ctype = $('#ctype').val();
  console.log(companyname);
  console.log(fname);
  console.log(username);
  console.log(countrycode);
  console.log(mobile);
  console.log(captcha);
  console.log(countryid);
  console.log(ctype);
  if(companyname == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Enter Company Name',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(fname == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Enter Admin Name',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(username == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Enter Admin Email',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(countrycode == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Select Country Code',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(mobile == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Enter Admin Mobile',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(captcha == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Enter Captcha',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(countryid == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Select Country',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Home/createcsoorpartner_submit",
        data: {
          companyname: companyname,
          fname: fname,
          countryid: countryid,
          mobile: mobile,
          email: email,
          countrycode: countrycode,
          captcha: captcha,
          ctype: ctype,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          resultObj = $.parseJSON(data);
          console.log(resultObj);
          if(resultObj.result == "success") {
            Swal.fire({
              title: resultObj.msg,
              width: 500,
              padding: '1em',
              background: '#fff',
              backdrop: `
                rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
                left top
                no-repeat
              `
            }).then(function (result) {
                    if (result.value) {
                      window.location = "<?php //echo base_url(); ?>Home";
                    }
                  })
          } else {
            Swal.fire({
              title: resultObj.msg,
              width: 500,
              padding: '1em',
              background: '#fff',
              backdrop: `
                rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
                left top
                no-repeat
              `
            })
          } 
        }
  })(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving all the values in your controller?

Comment: No. i tried to print the post values. but it is not calling that url also.
public function createcsoorpartner_submit() {
        print_r('hi');

Comment: data: { companyname: "" } pass only this in data and then check is it reaching the controller. In the controller. Do echo to see if it has reached the path

Comment: ok. i will check

Comment: yes it is working if i post only companyname

Comment: Alright so the issue is in the data that you are passing. Go inside the else part and console.log all values being passed. See if anyone of them is missing

Comment: In Console iam getting all the values which i passed.

Pro Tech One
Nazeer
protechone@gmail.com
91
7897897891
x09mw
812
Clinic_Admin

Comment: try omitting one of the values one by one and check if it works. Ajax is having issues with one the data values.

Comment: with email parameter iam getting this issue. instead of username i am posting it in ajax as email. Now this issue was fixed. but in ctype i am getting empty value in controller. but in console iam getting the value.

Comment: Where is your email variable? I cant find any email variable in your code. You are using username variable for email field. just pass username instead of email variable and it should work

Comment: yes its work good. but in ctype iam getting empty value in controller. before ajax in console iam getting the correct value.

Comment: Show ss of response in controller.

Comment: its working good now. thank you so much for the help

Comment: Alright great, if it was helpful accept the answer and vote.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is one that `$.ajax` will generate if you try to pass a structure that has [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) in it.

If the data definition type is incorrect, the data cannot be successfully sent to the background. The background does not receive the data, the front end will always sent, and this loop causes the stack to overflow.

So all you have to do is keep in check that the parameters you are sending in ajax are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
function submit() {
  var companyname = $('#companyname').val();
  var fname = $('#fname').val();
  var username = $('#email').val();
  var countrycode = $('#country-code').val();
  var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
  var captcha = $('#captcha').val();
  var countryid = $('#country-list').val();
  var userrole = $('#ctype').val();
  
  if(companyname == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Enter Company Name',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(fname == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Enter Admin Name',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(username == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Enter Admin Email',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(countrycode == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Select Country Code',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(mobile == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Enter Admin Mobile',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(captcha == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Enter Captcha',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else if(countryid == '') {
    Swal.fire({
          title: 'Select Country',
          width: 500,
          padding: '1em',
          background: '#fff',
          backdrop: `
            rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
            left top
            no-repeat
          `
        })
  } else {
    console.log(companyname);
  console.log(fname);
  console.log(username);
  console.log(countrycode);
  console.log(mobile);
  console.log(captcha);
  console.log(countryid);
  console.log(userrole);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Home/createcsoorpartner_submit",
        data: {
          companyname: companyname,
          fname: fname,
          countryid: countryid,
          mobile: mobile,
          email: username,
          countrycode: countrycode,
          userrole: userrole,
          captcha: captcha,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          var resultObj = $.parseJSON(data);
          console.log(resultObj);
          if(resultObj.result == "success") {
            Swal.fire({
              title: resultObj.msg,
              width: 500,
              padding: '1em',
              background: '#fff',
              backdrop: `
                rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
                left top
                no-repeat
              `
            }).then(function (result) {
                    if (result.value) {
                      window.location = "<?php //echo base_url(); ?>Home";
                    }
                  })
          } else {
            Swal.fire({
              title: resultObj.msg,
              width: 500,
              padding: '1em',
              background: '#fff',
              backdrop: `
                rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
                left top
                no-repeat
              `
            })
          } 
        }
  });
  }
}
```